# Are all embeddings of $D^n$ into $R^n$ ambiently homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

To make the question more precise: let $i, j : D^n \to R^n$ be topological embeddings. Does there exist a topological automorphism $h : R^n \to R^n$ such that $h \circ i = j$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes if $n=1$ (easy).
- Yes if $n=2$ (not easy: this follows from the [Jordan–Schönflies theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem))
- No if $n\ge 3$. The classical counterexample is the [Alexander horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). When filled in, it is homeomorphic to closed $3$-ball. However, the exterior is not simply connected and therefore is not homeomorphic to the exterior of the standard $3$-ball.